# Vagrant installing Java6SDK from Oracle

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

Just recently downloaded Oracle JavaSDK 6 (6u45).

Would want to know how to do a shell provision to install the `.bin` file provided by Oracle. I know there are better alternatives (online repository) but those consumes times and I'm limited to use JavaSDK 6 since the server I'm replicating requires me to use Java6.

Any hint how this can be done via shell provisioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [installation instruction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-64-self-extracting-142068.html) of Oracle. I would write shell script that follows this instruction. This shell script should be called by vagrant during the provision